# Output Data From MYSQL Table Into HTML Form Depending On User Choice

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a MYSQL table (roomcost) that holds the costs of hiring rooms.

```
costID  Room    Cost
1       room1   15
2       room2   30
3       room3   50
```

rsRoomCost SQL is: `SELECT * FROM roomcost`

The HTML form has checkboxes that allow the hirer to make the choice of Room 1, Room 2 or Room 3. The hirer can hire one, any two or all three rooms.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="room1" value="room1" onClick="Check()">Room 1</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="room2" value="room2" onClick="Check()">Room 2</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="room3" value="room3" onClick="Check()">Room 3</div>
```

The form also has an input box (that will be hidden, once I get it working) for each room that will be filled with the appropriate cost from the table. When the form is submitted, the hirers record would hold the choice of room(s) and cost paid by that hirer at the time of hiring.

The JS script that checks if a particular checkbox is selected and would output the cost to the relevant input box.

```
function Check() {
    if (document.forms["bookform"].room1.checked) {
        document.forms["bookform"].thisRoom1.value = "<?php echo($row_rsRoomCost['room1']; ?>";
    } else if (document.forms["bookform"].room2.checked) {
        document.forms["bookform"].thisRoom2.value = "<?php echo($row_rsRoomCost['room2']; ?>";
    } else if (document.forms["bookform"].room3.checked) {
        document.forms["bookform"].thisRoom3.value = "<?php echo($row_rsRoomCost['room3']; ?>";
    } 
}
```

The input boxes for the output are:

```
Room 1: <input type="text" name="thisRoom1" value="">
Room 2: <input type="text" name="thisRoom2" value="">
Room 3: <input type="text" name="thisRoom3" value="">
```

As you see, I'm trying to use php to fill in the relevant value from the database table. However, this, of course, only shows the cost from the first record in the costs table regardless of which room is checked.

How do I get the cost of the chosen room from the table into the correct input box on the form?

I've tried `<?php echo($row_rsRoomCost['room1']) where ($row_rsRoomCost['costID']) = '1'; ?>` but this doesn't work. I thought about 'case' statements but don't know how that would work. The only way I can think of is a seperate SQL statement for each room. eg: `SELECT * FROM roomcost WHERE costID = 1`

How do I get the cost of the selected room from the table into the correct input box on the form?

Comment: Why do you want to show the price in Input fields as they are from the database? I find logical issue in your approach. Code is secondary.

Comment: Yes. If the hirer checks the Room 1 checkbox, the relevant input field shows the cost from the database.

Comment: @TheDad  Checkboxes are only posted to the server when they are checked.  So the value of all of the checkboxes should be populated with the cost on page load.  Then when the form is submitted, you will only receive the rooms that have been checked, and therefor you will only get the cost of the rooms that have been checked.

Comment: Why not you display the relevant cost in a label instead? To pass on the data with the cost and selected room can be easily done with just one field instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through your code I find that that would be the long way round of solving it .

- The first step to solving it would be to put your data into a reusable front End source like JSON (it easier to work with ).

Example: (Results are in the console log F12)

```
                <?php

            $servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "jono23";
            $dbname = "helpothers";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `roomcost`";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            // echo "id: " . $row["costID"]. " - Name: " . $row["room"]. " " .$row["cost"]. "<br>";


                            // data you want to send to json
                            $data[] = array(
                                    'id' => $row['costID'],
                                    'room' => $row['room'],
                                    'cost' => $row['cost']
                            );

                            //}

                    }
            } else {
                    echo "0 results";
            }
            $conn->close();



            $json_data = json_encode($data);


            //print_r($json_data);






            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
            <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                    <form id='bookform' >
                            <input type="checkbox" name="room1" value="room1" onClick="Check()">Room 1</input>
                            <input type="text" name="room1value"  readonly><br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="room2" value="room2" onClick="Check()">Room 2</input>
                            <input type="text" name="room2value"  readonly><br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="room3" value="room3" onClick="Check()">Room 3</input>
                            <input type="text" name="room3value" readonly><br>
                    </form >
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    var Rooms = JSON.parse('<?php print_r($json_data) ; ?>');

                    console.log(Rooms);


                    function Check() {

                            //room1
                            if (document.forms["bookform"].room1.checked)
                            {
                                    document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value = Rooms[0].cost;
                                    console.log(Rooms[0].cost);
                            }else{
                                    document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value ='';
                            }

                            //room2
                            if (document.forms["bookform"].room2.checked)
                            {
                                    document.forms["bookform"].room2value.value = Rooms[1].cost;
                                    console.log(Rooms[1].cost);
                            }else{
                                    document.forms["bookform"].room2value.value ='';
                            }


                            //room3
                            if (document.forms["bookform"].room3.checked)
                            {
                                    document.forms["bookform"].room3value.value = Rooms[2].cost;
                                    console.log(Rooms[2].cost);
                            }else{
                                    document.forms["bookform"].room3value.value ='';
                            }
                    }



                    </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

- By encoding the SQL query results into a json array first you able to
  close the database connection so not to use up unnecessary resources
  on multiple requests
- Then By calling that PHP JSON Object into JavaScript you can more easily apply it to your html and JavaScript Needs
- Converting PHP Data To JSON and parse with JavaScript Help us work with things like rest api's

This is the main reason why JSON implementation can be found in many languages as its an easy way to share data across different coding languages

Another suggestion that I would make for the handling of the data is not to store the values in a checkboxes . Create another text input for that purpose and store them there . e.g

```
<input type='text' id='gethandle1'>
<script>
let box1 = document.getElementById('gethandle1');
box1.value = Rooms[0].cost; 
</script>
```

I hope this helps you .

Comment: Thanks for this. At the moment the data outputs to the top of the page, which I presume is due to the `print_r($json_data);`.However, I can't get the script tp put the data into the relevant input boxes. Re-reading my question, I don't think I make that bit very clear, so I've edited the question and added it in.

Comment: I've also just noticed and error in the JS code I wrote in the question, which would account for the (sensible) statement you make about not storing the values in the checkboxes.

Comment: Yes possibly what you would want to do is create a text box next to the check box and make that non editable to a users input (ie manually typing the text cost in ) 

So I will edit my explanation to reflect that

Comment: Another Change i made was to add an else statement to your code so if the box is unchecked the resulting value will default ... I updated my answers to reflect the changes ...

Comment: The data isn't being put into the input boxes the the the checkbox is checked. Using the console in FF shows `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`. The line is question is `var Rooms = JSON.parse('<? print_r($json_data); ?>');`. The second message is `SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`. If you click a checkbox, the console shows `TypeError: Rooms is undefined` which points to `document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value = Rooms[0].cost; console.log(Rooms[0].cost);`. What have I missed?

Comment: Ive copied the code as is from the example and it works fine on firefox ...

Perhaps your server is not set up to handle short PHP tag's <? ... ?> and needs to handle the longer one <?php  also just check you not running the file locally  from the drive and using it on the server .

Comment: For crying out loud! I saw this and thought about that but did nothing about it as I know you can use short tags. It didn't occur to me that I hadn't set the .ini file. As an aside, could you put another brick in my education and tell me what the `let  js = [{'212':'4454'},{'2':'21'},{'1':'223'}];` and `console.log(js[0]['212']);` is for and what they mean?

Comment: That was a sample I tested for another question. The guys problem was when referring an object with a key and value pair he could not make reference to it if it was numeric  per the dot notation i.e js[0].'212' ... his browser threw an error so I suggested he use the bracket notation ...

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I commented out all the 'console' statements and everything still works the same. There's still the 'legal expression' error but if I didn't run the console in Firefox I wouldn't be any the wiser of its existance. Once again, many thanks for your help, it is very much appreciated.