# Output two pieces of data if both statements are true

Tags: javascript, json

@JonoJames answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941437/output-data-from-mysql-table-into-html-form-depending-on-user-choice) for me.

The HTML form we use has a set of checkboxes which are checked depending on which room is being hired. These boxes are named `room1, room2 and room3`. When one, two or all three boxes are checked, the cost of that rooms hire is put into corresponding, hidden, input boxes named `room1value, room2value and room3value`.

We later needed to add deposits for the room hire which we did by adding, for example, `document.forms["bookform"].room1deposit.value = Rooms[0].deposit;` to the `function check()` script for each of the rooms. This added the deposit for the room automatically and it worked fine.

However now, occasionally, a deposit may not be required, so we put a checkbox in the form that is checked when a deposit *is* required. This checkbox, which is called `depositRequired`, covers all three rooms. So if someone hires *Room 1* and a deposit is required, boxes `room1` and `depositRequired` are checked. Similarly, If the boxes for *Room 2 and Room 3* are checked and a deposit is required, the `depositRequired` checkbox is selected too. If a room or rooms are hired and a deposit is not required, the required room boxes are checked but the `depositRequired` checkbox remains unselected.

We've tried `((document.forms["bookform"].room1value.checked) || (document.forms["bookform"].room1deposit.checked))`, `((document.forms["bookform"].room1deposit.checked) && (document.forms["bookform"].room1value.checked))` to the `if` statements and we've tried adding and `else if` to the statements, separate `if` statements and variations of the above but we can't get anything to work.

Our current code is:

```
function Check() {

    //room1
    if (document.forms["bookform"].room1.checked)
    {
        document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value = Rooms[0].cost;
        document.forms["bookform"].room1deposit.value = Rooms[0].deposit;
        //console.log(Rooms[0].cost);
    }else{
        document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value ='';
        document.forms["bookform"].room1deposit.value = '';
    }

    //room2
    if (document.forms["bookform"].room2.checked)
    {
        document.forms["bookform"].room2value.value = Rooms[1].cost;
        document.forms["bookform"].room2deposit.value = Rooms[1].deposit;
        //console.log(Rooms[1].cost);
    }else{
        document.forms["bookform"].room2value.value ='';
        document.forms["bookform"].room2deposit.value = '';
    }


    //room3
    if (document.forms["bookform"].room3.checked)
    {
        document.forms["bookform"].room3value.value = Rooms[2].cost;
        document.forms["bookform"].room3deposit.value = Rooms[2].deposit;
        //console.log(Rooms[2].cost);
    }else{
        document.forms["bookform"].room3value.value ='';
        document.forms["bookform"].room3deposit.value = '';
    }
}
```

and the output boxes are:

```
<input type="hidden" name="room1value" readonly>
<input type="hidden" name="room1deposit" readonly>
<input type="hidden" name="room2value" readonly>
<input type="hidden" name="room2deposit" readonly>
<input type="hidden" name="room3value" readonly>
<input type="hidden" name="room3deposit" readonly>
```

How do we add the deposit if the deposit checkbox is checked and the specific room is checked?

For example, if Room 1 is checked the cost of the room is output to the `room1value` input box but the deposit cost for Room1 is output to the input box `room1deposit` only if the deposit required checkbox is checked else it remains blank.

Comment: What is the name of the deposit checkbox? It is not included in your HTML, and your attempts reference the hidden input boxes, not the check boxes.

Comment: Also, what if deposit is checked, but corresponding room not? What should happen? It would be helpful if you would provide the HTML of the whole form.

Comment: Please accept my apologies. I didn't occur to me to add the information regarding the checkbox names and extra details. I have updated the question to include more detail regarding the checkboxes and how they relate to the Javascript and input boxes..

Comment: OK, I updated my answer in light of  this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your attempts you have tried using `room1value.checked` and `room1deposit.checked`, but those are not check boxes, but the hidden inputs in which you want to write the amounts. Instead you should use `depositRequired.checked`.

So you would need a nested `if`, like this:

```
if (document.forms["bookform"].room1.checked) {
    document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value = Rooms[0].cost;
    if (document.forms["bookform"].depositRequired.checked) { // <--- Additional IF
        document.forms["bookform"].room1deposit.value = Rooms[0].deposit;
    }
} // ... etc
```

I would however also point out that you can shorten your code a bit, as it currently has a lot of repetition.

Secondly, it would be good if you would use a lower case first letter for your function `check` and array `rooms`, as an initial capital is commonly used for class names (constructors).

Here is how you could deal with all three groups in a single loop:

```
function check() { // <--- initial char lower case
    let frm = document.forms["bookform"]; // avoid reading the document repetitively

    for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        // Use dynamic properties all over...
        frm[`room${i}value`].value = ""; // default
        frm[`room${i}deposit`].value = ""; // default
        if (frm[`room${i}`].checked) { 
            frm[`room${i}value`].value = rooms[i].cost; // lowercase
            if (frm.depositRequired.checked) { // <--- Additional IF
               frm[`room${i}deposit`].value = rooms[i].deposit; // lowercase
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question to give more detail but if a checkbox for a room is selected, the cost if that room is entered into the relevant input box as is the deposit required for the hire of each room selected, if a deposit is payable.