# If checkbox checked, use a different output

Tags: javascript

I need a small change to a piece of code to a question answered here: [Output two pieces of data if both statements are true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129273/output-two-pieces-of-data-if-both-statements-are-true) by [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot).

I now need to add an extra check, to allow a different room cost, if a particular checkbox is checked.

The piece of code I'm trying to alter is:

```
if (document.forms["bookform"].room1.checked) {
    document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value = Rooms[0].cost;
    if (document.forms["bookform"].depositRequired.checked) { // <--- Additional IF
        document.forms["bookform"].room1deposit.value = Rooms[0].deposit;
    }
} // ... etc
```

I tried adding:

```
if (document.forms["bookform"].agroup.checked) && (document.forms["bookform].room1.checked)
    {
        document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value = Rooms[0].redcost
    }
```

to the beginning of the code, as this seems to be the correct place to put the checked and use an 'else if' for the rest of the code, but this doesn't work, so, how and where do I insert the extra check?

Comment: Is redcost condition similar to deposit? - Meaning if room1 is checked, then check if agroup is checked if so, update the room1value? are you trying to acheive this?

Comment: If 'redgroup' is checked, then a deposit won't be required, it only applies to the room cost which is why I thought it should come first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (document.forms["bookform"].room1.checked) {
  if (document.forms["bookform"].agroup.checked) {
    document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value = Rooms[0].redcost
  } else {
    document.forms["bookform"].room1value.value = Rooms[0].cost;
    if (document.forms["bookform"].depositRequired.checked) {
      document.forms["bookform"].room1deposit.value = Rooms[0].deposit;
    }
  }

}
```

The piece of code above checks if room1 is checked (common condition for redcost,deposit and cost). If so, then it checks if agroup is checked and then it assigns only redcost to the room1value. Else, it applys just the cost alone. Since, deposit is not applicable in the presence of redcost, we have moved it to the else block. Hope this helps!