# insert one or more rows from an HTML form

Tags: php, html

I realise that this may be a duplicate question but I can't seem to find the right answer.

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into a MySQL table but, at the moment, all I'm doing is inserting the same data multiple times.

The table is called 'tblRoomsBooked' and the fields are `bookingNumber, roomID, roomRate` and `depositRate`. The table has it's own unique, primary key, `roomBookedID` which auto-increments.

We have an HTML form for booking rooms that we hire out. There are four rooms that can be hired in any combination. Each room has its own ID, hire cost and deposit amount required. So, for example, if one room was booked with a deposit, there should be one record inserted consisting of the booking number, the room's ID, the room's cost and its deposit. If three rooms were to be hired, there should be three separate records inserted, each record would hold the room ID, room cost and deposit of each room booked but all the rooms booked at the one time would have the same booking number.

The SQL code is:

```
$bookingNumber = ($_POST['bookingNumber']);
$roomID = ($_POST['roomID']);
$roomRate = ($_POST['roomRate']);
$depositRate = ($_POST['depositRate']);

$RoomsBooked = "INSERT INTO tblRoomsBooked (bookingNumber, roomID, roomRate, depositRate) VALUES ('$bookingNumber', '$roomID', '$roomRate', '$depositRate')";
```

If I use $RoomsBooked = `"INSERT INTO tblRoomsBooked (bookingNumber, roomID, roomRate, depositRate) VALUES ('$bookingNumber', '$roomID', '$roomRate', '$depositRate'), ('$bookingNumber', '$roomID', '$roomRate', '$depositRate'). ('$bookingNumber', '$roomID', '$roomRate', '$depositRate'), ('$bookingNumber', '$roomID', '$roomRate', '$depositRate')";` as I read elsewhere here, it just creates four rows of the same data, regardless of the combination of rooms selected.

The rooms are selected by checkboxes...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxMargins" id="meetingRoom" name="roomID" value="1" onClick="Check();">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxMargins" id="library" name="roomID" value="2" onClick="Check();">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxMargins" id="jajRoom" name="roomID" value="3" onClick="Check();">
<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxMargins" id="annex" name="roomID" value="4" onClick="Check();">
```

When a checkbox is selected, some JQuery scripting by [JonoJames](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1978210/jonojames) which can be found here [Output Data From MYSQL...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941437/output-data-from-mysql-table-into-html-form-depending-on-user-choice) is used to fill hidden input boxes for the room costs.

I've tried using `name="roomID[]` but this throws an error regarding arrays and not liking the `INSERT` statement.

All this works perfectly for booking one room, it's just if more than one is booked that I can't make work.

I think I need to use `for` or `foreach` but the examples on here don't really show how to take the data from the form to insert it into the table.

What I need to know is, if `for` or `foreach` is the way to go, what to do and how to use it. If not, what do I need to do?

Comment: I think you need to give us an example of your form or explain how someone books 1 or up to 4 rooms. If someone books X rooms, you will need X number of values to insert.So how do you get those?

Comment: Split your task in two parts: 1. sending an array of data from HTML to php. 2. Inserting multiple rows from an array in PHP.

Comment: @YourCommonSense. I tried splitting it as you suggested but I'm still getting the same result. It's as though the `value=` in an `input` tag isn't being read.

Comment: I cannot tell you anything useful really, being given such a morsel of information. You may want to edit your question, providing HTML used and the array of data you get in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

All it needed was to put a `0` into the JavaScript wherever the value of the deposit was `''`

For example. In the JavaScript there are lines similar to `document.forms["bookform"].room1valueDeposit.value ='';`. This need's to be `document.forms["bookform"].room1valueDeposit.value ='0';`.

I had tried replacing the `''` in the script with`0` but I had replaced all `''` not just those relating to deposits. This way, if a room was booked but no deposit was required, it would fill the field with a zero not an empty string and if a deposit was required, the deposit amount would be entered.

Can't believe something so small could take so long to figure out.

Answer (score -1):

As you didn't share any information about the `HTML` code, it is really hard to understand your booking process.

Regarding your multiple inserts, you already stated the correct approach. If you send your formular to the backend, you have to send each Booking of the room to the backend. This array contains multiple objects, depending on how many books have been booked.

Every obect should contain your necesarry data, roomID,  roomRate, deposite and more. As you said, yes it is possible to loop through that array and then insert every booking into the database.

The error you get, is that you insert the same data over and over again, because you do not loop or didn't correctly fetch your next booking. If you share more code, we can take a look.

Comment: I've added the HTML code that selects the rooms and a link to the JQuery code by JonoJames that gets the room costs.

Comment: regarding multiple inserts, the current approach is *anything* but correct

Comment: @YourCommonSense. Your comment doesn't really help. I know it's "*anything* but correct" which is why I'm asking.

Comment: @TheDad you've got it a bit confused. Here I commented on the answer, not your question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense. Please accept my apologies. You said earlier to split the data into two parts, one part being an array and the second inserting the data into the table. What would you suggest is the best way?